# Play reloads application on static assets update in dev mode

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

How does Play determine a need to reload application (stop + start) in dev mode? I'm confused when Play reloads application on every **public** or **assets** change - this takes a lot of time (3-6 seconds) and is absolutely unnecessary.

Is there any way to customize this? Is this a bug?

Comment: Known [issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2905) at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. By default Play will compile assets (JS, LESS), but up to recently this was not very performant. As of Play 2.3, the new [sbt-web](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web#sbt-web) project makes it possible to use `node.js` directly for these operations, which is much faster.

See also [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets) on the topic

Comment: Manuel, the problem is not with notable compilation time, my problem is with application reload. On assets change application restart is useless.